# Implementation of quartic equation solver doesn't work

Tags: python, math, equation, solver

What's going wrong with my implementation of a quartic equation solver?
Here is my code [on GitHub](https://github.com/rubik/pypol/blob/master/pypol/roots.py#L242). I followed this: http://www.1728.com/quartic2.htm
In fact the real implementation starts at line 271, where I create the monic poly.

If I try it with a polynomial with 4 real roots it works fine (for example with 3x^4 + 6x^3 - 123x^2 - 126x + 1,080), otherwise gives wrong roots.

Thanks,
rubik

P.S. I called the function `__quartic` because it is still in development

Comment: Can you (1) Post just the smallest relevant piece of code and (2) an actual example showing what you expected and what actually happened.  It helps if you lay it all out carefully and completely.

Comment: Double leading underscores are nothing but pain waiting to happen. Don't even start getting used to it. Inside classes, names get mangled and you get mysterious name errors - and zero benefit. Use a single leading underscore for private stuff and none for everything else (including stuff in development). Also see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @ delnan: I try to follow PEP 8, and I think I have done no style-errors in my code. As I said, I used double leading underscores only to warn that it was still in development. But now I've renamed it to `quartic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it isn't a problem with your cubic solver (as phkahler suggested), then I'm betting that it is a case of int division in these lines:

```
f = float(c - (3*b**2 / 8))
g = float(d + (b**3/ 8) - (b*c / 2))
h = e - (3*b**4 / 256) + (b**2 * c / 16) - (b*d / 4)
```

If you are using a version of Python that is less than 3.0 and not importing division from `__future__`, then you can have major problems here. For instance, if b = 3, then `(3*b**2/8)` is equal to 3 by int division rather than the correct float division value of 3.375. Probably the best way to correct this is to convert a,b,c,d and e to floats before you start doing calculations. Your conversion to float after all of the calculations for f and g are really unnecessary after you've made this correction and they aren't really helping you much now.

For more information about this division issue and its history see:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/03/problem-with-integer-division.html

Comment: Ok, thank you. Converting a, b, c, d and e to floats it works.

Answer (score 1):

Does your cubic root solver work? You should have it reduced to only returning a single real root for use within the quartic solver. Run a number of test cases on the cubic solver first, including equations with both 1 and 3 real roots. Only after this is verified should you try to debug the quartic solver.

Comment: Yes, it works fine, I tested it with many polys. Of course when roots are complex numbers it can't be perfect...

Comment: There will always be at least one real root. This is the one you need to return to the quartic solver. Anyway, good to know it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I can help out.  I wrote [a program and the procedure for solving quartic equations](http://www.1728.com/quartic.htm).

I'm guessing you are not writing the program in JavaScript.
I'd be willing to help out (if I can).

Comment: Ehm no I'm not. Unfortunately I'm writing the program in Python for the pypol project (https://github.com/rubik/pypol). Can I contact you? How? Thank you, rubik

Comment: rubik   My E-Mail is wolf@1728.com